Physics with a grappling hook Unity 2D
I am trying to make a grappling hook and found plenty of tutorials but they aren't what I am going for, I tried taking parts of the codes from tutorials but nothing worked correctly for me and I'm also relatively new to programming so I'm having a difficult time, I want something like this from Ori.
https://youtu.be/5Nx188VW8kk
I have tried spring joints, slider joints, Addforce with impulse, they somewhat work but I keep running into the SAME problem with physics, if the player stands under the target of the grapple, I get launched way further up into the sky than if I did it from the side, I have tried lowering the gravity, the weight and everything I could think of on the player's rigidbody but nothing works correctly, if anyone has any ideas how to get the the desired effect that would be greatly appreciated!!
